# how to add for loop control

Tags: c#

I try to add check box for loop that when i enter 3 for example in textbox and click the button it automatically add 3 check boxes in the form
i tried this code but only add one check box

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                                                         
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        int m = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            CheckBox button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();



            button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, m);
            button2.Name = "button2 "+  m.ToString();
            button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(51, 23);
            button2.TabIndex = m;

            //button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;

            this.Controls.Add(button2);
            m++;



        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are setting the location of all three buttons to nearly the same place so they are displayed on top of each other. Try spacing them out a little more.

For example change `m++;` to `m += 40;`.

Comment: And then don't use `m` for `TabIndex`. +1

Answer (score 0):

You need to space your buttons out a little. Also, you should give each of your buttons a unique ID.

```
button2.ID = "Button_" + i;
```